# prevent jquery validation submitting upon error

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I use this in jquery it works as should however when live it is not and it is the exact same code as I copied and pasted.

When live when i select yes for the radio button it asks me to select colour and shade as it should but then it submits when i click ok. If i select attendance1 yes and select the 2 drop down values it submits without error on attendance1 or attendance2

Comment: do you have firebug installed? do you get any error on its console?

Comment: May help to post a link to the code that does not work rather than a version that does, as this is most often because of something contextual to the whole page.

Comment: paste the error you have in firebug console

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo updated scenario

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo on line 200 I am getting Expected '}' and on line 201 I am getting "Syntax error". line 201 ends the javascript </script> and line 200 is the very last });

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're running jQuery in "noclobber" mode (where it avoids setting itself as the `$` variable).

Try putting this around the whole above code snippet:

```
(function($) {
    // ... code here
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: no this does not work however please see editted post I have updated scenario as to what happens thanks

Comment: `if (!$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {` looks suspicious to me since it is designed to select multiple elements, then examine the property of one of them; try `if (!$("input[name=attendance1]:checked").length) {`.

Comment: which i do not understand because I am return false; everytime